# Generate name for Excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a template in excel, with which I make reports from my application.

Each time I generate a report, it is saved in a folder with a fixed name and a variable so that it is not always the same document.

I have this code to open the template

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel._Workbook book;
    Excel._Worksheet sheet;
    libro = app.Workbooks.Open(@"path", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

With this I save and I generate the name with a counter in 0

```
string paths= @"path";
            string name= "Report_.xlsx";
            while (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(paths, name)))
            {

                int i = 1;

                name= string.Format("Report_{0}.xlsx",i);


            }
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(paths, name);
            book.SaveAs(fullpath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            book.Close(0);
            app.Quit();
```

The problem is that I can only generate two reports but then I try to generate a third party and the application gets stuck and I do not get any exception, it only gets stuck, but it's only when I try to generate a third document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not increasing variable "i". You should declare it outside while loop and then increase before usage:

```
string paths= @"path";
            string name= "Report_.xlsx";
            int i = 0;
            while (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(paths, name)))
            {

                  i++;

                name= string.Format("Report_{0}.xlsx",i);


            }
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(paths, name);
            book.SaveAs(fullpath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            book.Close(0);
            app.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your counter variable initialisation outside of the loop

```
string paths= @"path";
            string name= "Report_.xlsx";
            int i = 1;
            while (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(paths, name)))
            {   
                name= string.Format("Report_{0}.xlsx",i);

                i++;
            }
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(paths, name);
            book.SaveAs(fullpath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            book.Close(0);
            app.Quit();
```